# Is it mandatory a test class for a trigger when we deploy things into production..?

Tags: trigger

I am trying to upload my application package for another org. That application has some triggers and it showing an error while uploading. can anyone help me out in this problem

Comment: Could you please provide the error and the code linked to this error?

Comment: In the Salesforce documentation it makes it clear that Apex always needs to have test classes and a code coverage of 75% before deployment to another org.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write test code for whatever Apex code you have in the org (Apex Class, Apex Trigger, Batch class, etc).

As the message says, you need at least 75% overall code coverage which you will get only when proper test code is written.

Read this for more: [Apex Test Classes](https://developer.salesforce.com/page/An_Introduction_to_Apex_Code_Test_Methods)